# My navigator bar doesnt wants to be colored

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a site but I'm trying to set the navigator bar at the right and that works good but when I'm trying to give the `<ul>` a color it doesn't give it the color if I remove `float:right;` it only works.

Does someone knows how to do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styling.css">
    <head>
    <body>
        <div class="navi">
            <ul>
                <li>Contact</li>
                <li>Portfolio</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Home</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

    div.navi li {
    font-size:30px;
    display:inline-block;
    width:12%;
    float:right;
}

div.navi {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your HTML/CSS code?

Comment: css:
https://pastebin.com/yu6LLX36
html:
https://pastebin.com/4YPCz46p

Comment: Please post the code into your topic, not via pastebin, or atleast make a jsfiddle

Comment: I did it is it good now?

Comment: No, it&#39;s not good now. Where even is the `&lt;style&gt;` tag? And is that nav bar the _only_ thing in your code? If not, add it. The code isn't indented properly either. Fix all of it, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Your `div` should have some `width` and `height`

```css
div.navi li {
    font-size:20px;
    padding-right:10px;
    float:right;
}

.navi {
    background-color:red;
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
}

ul{
  list-style:none;
}
```

```html
    <div class="navi">
            <ul>
                <li>Contact</li>
                <li>Portfolio</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Home</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div.navi { 
    background: red; 
    float: right; 
    width: 12%; 
}

div.navi li { 
    font-size: 30px; 
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

Please try

Answer (score 0):

Since `div.navi` only contains floated elements, it doesn't have any height of its own (i.e. height 0), so you don't see any background color.

To avoid this (and let `div.navi` wrap the `li`elements), add `overflow: auto` to `div.navi`

```css
div.navi li {
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px 5px 10px;
  float: right;
}

div.navi {
  background-color: red;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="navi">
  <ul>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <li>Portfolio</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Home</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```